# How to deploy application configuration files using rocketeer?

Tags: php, symfony, rocketeer

I have a symfony2 application and I was checking rocketeer, it's very helpful so far. The only problem is, I didn't find a way to deploy changes to config files that are not committed to my git repository like for example ( app/config/parameters.yml ). Right now I just modified the file myself on the server. But, I wonder if there is a way to automate it using rocketeer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Schooley .. The solution is basically to ditch rocketeer

and start using [Deployer](http://deployer.org/) . It seems like a good alternative and has upload functionality

Answer (score 0):

Just create the configuration files on the server and add the files to your list of shared files, so it is symlinked into every release.

Deployer.org does it the same way, so there is no reason to choose Deployer.org over Rocketeer, if you already started with rocketeer.

Thanks to the creator of Rocketeer for this information: https://github.com/rocketeers/rocketeer/issues/722